# How do i capitalize each item in a list in a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to capitalize every item in a list inside a dictionary.

```
dict = {'name': 'Kevin', 'age':16, 'food':['chicken', 'pizza', 'burger'], 'shoes':'Adidas'}
```

I want every item in the list 'food' to be capitalized.

I tried doing this

```
dict['food'].title()
```

But it doesn't work. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

`title()` only operates on the string. You're accessing the list via `dict['food']`. You need to iterate over that list and call that function on each of them, and then change the value of `dict['food']`. Thankfully it can be done in one line with a list comprehension.

```
dict = {'name': 'Kevin', 'age':16, 'food':['chicken', 'pizza', 'burger'], 'shoes':'Adidas'}
dict['food'] = [food.title() for food in dict['food']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `capitalize` on every item in the list like this:

```
dict["food"] = [f.capitalize() for f in dict["food"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use item assignment to modify the list in place.

For example:

```
dct = {'name': 'Kevin', 'age':16, 'food':['chicken', 'pizza', 'burger'], 'shoes':'Adidas'}

lst = dct['food']

for i, val in enumerate(lst):
    lst[i] = val.title()

print(dct)
```

The alternative is to use an expression to generate a new list object with the correct values.  That is adequately covered by another answer and I won't repeat it here.

Also, do not call your dictionary `dict`. It is not good to override a builtin.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list and dictionary comprehension, combined with the lazily evaluating if then else syntax:

```
dict = {'name': 'Kevin', 'age':16, 'food':['chicken', 'pizza', 'burger'], 'shoes':'Adidas'}

result = {k:([i.title() for i in v] if isinstance(v,list) else v) for k,v in dict.items()}

print(result)
```